# subtracting qty in JS not working only some times

Tags: javascript, debugging, operators

So i'm new to JS and am working on a project to receive products based on tracking info and then with the UPC code, i get the package contents from a AJAX call to php then add the items to a array in js object format, when a UPC is scanned from a item in the package it should subtract one from the package content, the issue the function i made to subtract only works on some item objects not all and i can't seem to figure out why, there is no differences between the objects, what am i doing wrong

heres my code

```
//define array
`var packageContent = [];

//create item objects
var Item = function(name, upc, weight, qty) {
    this.name = name
    this.upc = upc
    this.weight = weight
    this.qty = qty
}

//with php info add items with the tracking to the package content
function addItemToPackage(name, upc, weight, qty) {
    for (var i in packageContent) {
        if (packageContent[i].upc == upc) {
            packageContent[i].qty += qty;
            return;
        }
    }
    item = new Item(name, upc, weight, qty);
    packageContent.push(item);
}`

//Package Content Lookup
function initialInboundScan(tracking) {
    //define tracking var
    var tracking = tracking;
    //AJAX request to PHP to find items assosiated with tracking #
    $.ajax({
    url : "./includes/process.php",
    method : "post",
    data : {inbound_tracking_scan:1,tracking:tracking},
    success : function(data)
        {
        var items = JSON.parse(data);
        //Loop the respone call addItemToPackage()
        for(var i in items){
        addItemToPackage(items[i].product_name, items[i].UPC, items[i].SKU, parseInt(items[i].qty)) 
        } 
        return packageContent;
        }
    });
}

// remove item from package
function remove(upc) {
    var upc = upc;
    for (var i in packageContent) {
        if (packageContent[i].upc == upc) {
            packageContent[i].qty --;
        if (packageContent[i].qty == 0) {
        packageContent.splice(i , 1);   
        }     
        }
    }
}
```

the remove() function wont work on items made with the initialInboundScan(); only items made directly with the addItemToPackage() and i cant seem to figure out why the remove() function wouldn't subtract from the qty

Comment: And what have you tried to debug the problem? Couldn't you step through the code to spot the difference?

Comment: @NicoHaase i tried finding a difference but can't, if you see one please enlighten me, greatly appreciated